# Websphere SOAP JMX NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, security, websphere

I am getting this Exception (see below) from calling Websphere AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props). I am using WSAD, and JRE is set to Project JRE which is (Websphere App Server v7.0 JRE)

Is there anything I am missing. jar? keystore? settings?

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

```
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSLContext Default implementation not found: ; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSLContext Default implementation not found: ]
    at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:469)
    at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Call.java:451)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:364)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the exception is:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSLContext Default implementation not found:
```

I assume it's something to do with your SSL certificate. Has it been installed correctly?

This [IBM Documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_birk/0612_birk.html) shows how to setup/configure SSL certificate on WAS.

Comment: I didn't install one, I am using the self-signed that generated by WAS by default. (and the funny thing is after the : it didn't show what exactly is the implementation not found)